# Is Inner Join needed when operating on one table?

Tags: mysql, join

There is a table `Employee` as below:

[image]

I need finds out employees who earn more than their managers and I figure out two methods:

1. `SELECT a.Name AS Employee FROM Employee a, Employee b WHERE a.Salary > b.Salary AND a.ManagerId = b.Id;`
2. `SELECT a.Name AS Employee FROM Employee a INNER JOIN Employee b ON a.Salary > b.Salary AND a.ManagerId = b.Id;`

Both of them work well and have close speed.

What's the difference between them?  Thanks.

Comment: Borh queries are identical, but the first one uses the now deprecated pre ANSI-92 join sintax (I call it sintax rather than syntax, because many gurus on this site consider it a sin to put join conditions in the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: But i think , both are correct but only for simple quires, For big queries  Join will be better, Join not only uses for filter but also for joining to table in efficient way  , But ' where '  only uses for filters.

Comment: They are same. However the most preferred Syntax is: SELECT staff.Name FROM Employee AS staff INNER JOIN Empolyee AS manager ON staff.ManagerId = manager.Id WHERE staff.Salary > manager.Salary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those queries are equivalent.  But you should use the `join` syntax instead of commas in the `from` clause.  [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Here's an alternative option which might have a better performance using `exists`:

```
select e.Name AS Employee
from employee e
where exists (
   select 1
   from employee e2
   where e.managerid = e2.id and e.salary > e2.salary
)
```